# Getting null or not an object error in javascript code

Tags: javascript, object, null

Here is the line which is causing null or not an object error

```
if(frm.elements["hdn_retain"+indexval].value==""){
   ....
} else {
   ....
}
```

Comment: Well, then the thing you're trying to access is probably `null` or not an object. Have you tried some step-by-step debugging of what `frm`, `frm.elements`, `frm.elements["hdn_retain"+indexval]` are?

Answer (score 0):

frm.elements["hdn_retain"+indexval] may be a null object. So, it will have error when getting the value. You can check the frm.elements["hdn_retain"+indexval] if it is null first.

```
if(frm.elements["hdn_retain"+indexval] != null && frm.elements["hdn_retain"+indexval].value=="")
```

Answer (score 0):

Either `frm` or `frm.elements["hdn_retain"+indexval]` isn't a valid object (doesn't exist in the dom) and therefore you can't access it's property.

you could try something like:

```
if(frm.elements["hdn_retain"+indexval] && frm.elements["hdn_retain"+indexval].value==""){
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the result of alert statement:

```
alert("frm:::"+frm);
alert("frm elements::::"+frm.elements);
alert("frm hdn_retain :: "+frm.elements["hdn_retain"+indexval]);

frm:::[object]
frm elements::::[object]
frm hdn_retain :: undefined
```

Comment: i would assume the `indexval` is defined and probably is inside of a loop.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this utility method `getProperty` i always use to make sure i get a nested namespace back without worrying about whether or not something is defined:

```
function getProperty(ns, obj) {
    var nsArray = ns.split('.'), 
        i       = 0, 
        nsLen   = nsArray.length;
    while (nsLen > 0) {
        var newNs = nsArray.shift();
        if (obj[newNs]) {
            obj = obj[newNs];
        } else { 
            return false;
        }
        nsLen = nsArray.length;
    }
    return obj;
};

var index = "hdn_retain" + indexval;
    // the following `value` will come back as a valid object/value or a false
    value = getProperty('elements.' + index + '.value', frm); 
if (value) {
  // do whatever
} else {
  // do not whatever
}
```

this can be applied not only to this situation but to any other situation you need to make sure a certain namespace is available before usage.